# UILabel not breaking .byWordWrapping when font size too big

Tags: swift, uilabel

My UILabel breaks and wraps perfectly when the font size is default, but when the font increases just a few points, the label does not break anymore (both when the font is custom or system). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = "Have you ever slipped on a banana peel?"
    titleLabel.frame.size.width = view.frame.width
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: displayBlack, size: 32.0)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.text
    view.addSubview(titleLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure the content is clipped to bounds.

```
titleLabel.clipsToBounds = true
```

and also there is enough space for the label to expand.

Comment: That's not the issue. The font size is the only variable that causes this problem and I can't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure there is enough space available for the label to break in 2 lines?

Comment: I can break 20 lines with system font without any problem but as soon as I increase the font size by even a point, I can't break a single line.

Comment: there is another thing to check. add the frame completely:
`titleLabel.frame = ...` and remove the `titleLabel.sizeToFit()`